# Are questions regarding 3rd party Esri extensions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I went back and forth on whether to post this question to the [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com):
[What is the maximum, allowable field length for a FacilityID field in a Cityworks geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/what-is-the-maximum-allowable-field-length-for-a-facilityid-field-in-a-cityworks)

ESRI extensions such as network analyst, spatial analyst have questions (and their own tags). My thinking was that GIS-related questions for systems like Cityworks (or any of the NAGCS members http://www.nagcs.org/members.asp) would be appropriate.  Thoughts?

Based on the answers I am getting, it seems the "Cityworks" aspect of the question was being ignored and the answers are for the geodatabase itself (*which may be correct for Cityworks*).   Is it a poorly worded question?  Inappropriate for this site?  Or maybe there are low numbers of Cityworks users who use http://gis.stackexchange.com and if I let the question hang out there, I'll get an answer?

Answer (score 12):

If it's something that relates to GIS (and an extension to ArcGIS Desktop certainly qualifies in that regard) then I think it's a valid question. You may not have as much luck in getting an answer here as on a dedicated forum relevant to the extension, but it's likely that someone here is at least familiar with the product and may provide useful help.